# Get plot points indicies

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, roi

If I need to get the indices of some plotted points on a `figure` or `axe` by using box selection like the following:

```
load cities
education = ratings(:,6);
arts = ratings(:,7);
plot(education,arts,'+')
```

[image: Plot demo image]

How to get the indices of these points in the vector `education` not from the `x axis` ?

I want the solution to be flexible not for this plot only. I want to get the indices of any set of points, using box selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(i)** If the # of points is small, you can use data cursor tool in the figure's gui.

**(ii)** You can use `find` or logical condition given some boundaries, for example:

```
  ind = find(arts>2e4 & education>2500 & education<3800);
  ans = arts(ind)`
```

so `plot(education(ind),arts(ind),'ro')` will show it:

[image]

**(iii)** you can select a box interactively with a `imrect`

```
h = imrect;
position = wait(h);
```

Then use the `position` (which is a vector of `[xmin ymin width height]`) values with `find` function:

```
ind =find(education>position(1) & education<position(1)+position(3) & ...
     arts>position(2) & arts<position(2)+position(4))
```

**Edit:**

After I was asked how polygon selection with `impoly` can be used, here is the solution:

```
h = impoly;
position = wait(h);
points_in= inpolygon(education,arts,position (:,1),position (:,2));
ind=find(points_in);
...
```

Comment: I want it to be flexible not only for these points, I want to get the indices of some points using selection box.

Comment: see the bottom part of the answer

Comment: that's a very nice answer, Can this be done also somehow using `impoly` ?

Comment: in `impoly` the `position` output is an n-by-2 array that specifies the initial position of the vertices of the polygon. `position` has the form [x1,y1;...;xn,yn].  So in order to only include the area you want you need a more sophisticated logical condition. The trick is that the # of  vertices in the polygon is not known, so you need to automatically make the `find` meet the # of vertices.

Comment: I've added a full solution to `impoly`